# Segue from ViewController to another Window Controller not calling PrepareForSegue

Tags: c#, xcode, macos, xamarin

I have a ViewController that comes from the main window. On that ViewController there is a button that opens up another window (a Split Window Controller) when pressed. For that, I created a Modal segue from the button (in View Controller) to the Split Window Controller I want to bring up. Because I want to pass information from the view controller to the new window, I override the PrepareForSegue method in ViewController.cs to look like this:

```
 public override void PrepareForSegue(NSStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

        // Take action based on the segue name
        switch (segue.Identifier)
        {
            case "ModalSegue":
                var dialog = segue.DestinationController as SplitWindowController;
                dialog.Presentor = this;
                dialog.Filename = filename;
                break;
        }
    }
```

And in the SplitWindowController.cs, I have the WindowDidLoad() method overriden and everything.

Now when I run the code, the button brings up the new Split Window Controller. However, I noticed that the information I want to pass is not getting passed. I put a breakpoint at the beginning of the PrepareForSegue method, expecting the app to pause when I press the button. However, it seems that the PrepareForSegue method has been skipped completely as the breakpoint was ignored and the Split Window Controller still shows up. I am in Debug mode, so the breakpoint should work.

I tried having another button that segues to a view controller rather than a window controller, and that works perfectly fine. It seems that the problem is connecting a segue to a window, and that WindowDidLoad() gets called regardless of PrepareForSegue.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you provide the SplitWindowController and the code that calls the PerformSegue?